# How to enable application insights for Azure Web App virtual directories

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-insights

I am running one ASP.NET application in Azure Web Apps. And I have enabled Application Insights for that web app and it is working properly. I have got two other applications inside this web app as virtual applications. But Application Insights not working for them.

[image: Application virtrual directories]

I can't add the Application Insights SDK to the specified virtual applications.

Is there a way I can configure application insights for the virtual applications, without adding SDK?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add the app insights SDK to all the app and be sure you set InstrumentationKey for each as well.

Comment: As I mentioned in the questions, I can't add the SDK to the project. And the root level app getting the insights without adding SDK.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that **Application insight could only run on root website**, and if you want to to get functional at virtual directory level, you could vote up this [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/357324-application-insights/suggestions/19614658-application-insight-to-get-functional-at-virtual-d) to promote the function to achieve.

BTW, the way you set up virtual applications may have some mistakes. You should set as below:

[image]

For more details, you could refer to the article-[Deploying multiple virtual directories to a single Azure Website](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tomholl/2014/09/21/deploying-multiple-virtual-directories-to-a-single-azure-website/).

Comment: Ok. Let me change it and will try.